# Electric oven in the same plug as a microwave

Tags: electrical, oven, microwave-oven

Can I have an electric oven in the same plug as a microwave, and if not how hard is it to change a single plug to a double?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Not only where are you , but are the electric oven and microwave using the same receptacle, are they factory ends or did someone put an after market plug cap on the microwave so it would fit the oven receptacle , in some locations the plug cap has fuses is this the type on the microwave? Lots of different possibilities here.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more info before we can help you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Be aware that just changing the socket from single to double does **not** change the wiring behind the socket - have that checked...

Comment: Can you describe further the microwave and oven?  "electric oven" covers a whole lot of territory...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in the US, and that when you speak of an electric oven you are referring to one of the electric toaster type ovens that sit on the counter. Is that correct? If so, you can used the same outlet for both, and convert it to a double outlet so you can have both plugged in at the same time. However, both devices draw a good bit of current when in use and if you try to use both at the same time you will most likely trip the breaker on the circuit.

Short answer, you can used the same outlet for both devices, but just not at the same time.

Comment: Yes this is true but having a dedicated circuit with a single outlet for microwave is necessary to be in compliance with code.

Comment: @Kris, surely that's only for "built in" style microwaves?  No one is putting in dedicated circuits for their $69 countertop microwave.

Comment: @JPhi1618  I know that anytime our 129 dollar countertop microwave is running and the blender is turned on the breaker trips. It is an old 15 amp circuit however.